# Haskell list comprehension doesn't work

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Here is a list comprehension I've made in Haskell:

```
[x|x <- [1..], n <- [1..], n <= 10, n >= 1, x == ((7 * n) + 4)]
```

I expect it to print out the first 10 natural numbers that are 4 mod 7, but when I execute it, it doesn't print out anything and never terminates. Why?

Comment: How could it terminate if both `x` and `n` grow infinitely?

Comment: *You* know that `n` is drawn from a monotonically increasing list, but the compiler does not.

Comment: Vincent: That's why I have the upper and lower bounds for n.

Comment: And the compiler has to check each and every potential value of `n` to make sure those bounds hold. Just because it finds *one* value of `n` that is greater than 10 doesn't mean it the next one might not be.

Comment: What does it print if you remove the `x ==` clause? Why?

Comment: You don't have bounds. `n` grows infinitely, and you have conditions on `n` that checks if it is between 1 and 10, which will always be false once `n` is greater than 10. If you wanted bounds, you would write `n <- [1..10]`, but your list would still grow infinitely since `x` grows infinitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not infer that `n <- [1..], n<=10, n >=1` is equivalent to `n <- [1..10]`. The code will merrily pull values of `n` from `[1..]` forever, verifying for each one whether it should be used or not per the guards `n <= 10` and `n >= 1`. `n <- [1..10]` without further tests on `n` would be sufficient, but if you want to be explicit, try something like

```
[x|x <- [1..], n <- takeWhile (<= 10) [1..], x == ((7 * n) + 4)]
```

Pulling `x` from a separate list and comparing them to a function of `n` is also inefficient. You can just construct your list from `n` alone:

```
[ 7*n + 4 | n <- [1..10] ]
```

Comment: Alright. That explains alot. Thank you very much :)